# ADD/DELETE column from xml mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I have some problem with hibernate. when I add a column `age` into the file mapping of `Client.xml`, hibernate update my table `client` and add the column, but when a delete the same column `age` from `Client.xml` and `client.java`, and I run my application, I found that the column still in my table `client`.
can anyone have a clue why hibernate couldn't delete the column `age` from table `client`
thank you ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate follow two approach
1. Schema first
2. Code first

In Schema first Java entities are created based on your database design and in Code first approach database is created with all java entities annotated with @Entity.

In your case you are following Code first approach, when you add any new column in java entity hibernate will create column on your behalf if `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` is `update`. if your database contains more tables hibernate has no issue with it that's why hibernate is not deleting any column if you delete it from Java Entity.

Comment: thank @atu_java, so how can i use the first approach "Shema first" ?

Comment: I think schema first approach will work only before building your war / jar. During running of application it wont be possible / not recommened one because it will try to change your java file and and hbm and you have to recompile it and reloading of class file is required so it wont work during runtime of your application.

Comment: For production people will set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to "validate" alone and they prefer to run the sqls using liquibase kind of tools during the application boot up time. it is easy for them to upgrade / downgrade their db

Comment: thanks everyone, i did add <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>  but when i try to run the application a get this message Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]

Comment: @maria Yes on prod we must use with validate mode.